# Issue executing python script from a Python script

Tags: python-3.x, rest

I have a script that I use to query an API my goal is to pass the returned Value from the first script to another python script for additional processing

Both scripts are written in python 3 and are being executed on a Linux system

Both scripts work as expected however when I attempt to pass the ID from the first script to the second script I receive an attribute error

Script one stores the data in a dictionary but I have stored the value I am looking for

```
#print(responseCode)
body = buffer.getvalue()
# Body is a byte string.
# We have to know the encoding in order to print it to a text file
# such as standard output.
res=json.loads(body.decode('iso-8859-1'))


# # Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data

results = res["result"]
sys_id = (results["sys_id"])
os.system("/tmp/test.py --event_id " + sys_id + " --status Down " + " --host " + args.host )
```

Whats weird is that when I create a sys_id variable with a string everything works just fine

i.e

```
sys_id = "123456"
```

but when the ID comes from the variable no go I verified that the variable is a string

Here is the function from script 2

```
def get_alert_id (event_id):
 headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}
 url= 'URL' + event_id
 response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )
 print(type(response))
 data = response.json()
 alert = data.get('result').get('alert').get('value')
 get_incident_id(alert)
```

when the script is executed from the shell it works just fine
This is the error I get when executed from the first python script

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 66, in <module>
    get_alert_id(event_id)
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 45, in get_alert_id
    alert = data.get('result').get('alert').get('value')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have used os.system and subprocess both yield the same error

Script two is using argparse for inputs I initially thought argparse was doing something funky when the values were being passed so I imported script2 into script 1 and called on the function but that also yield the same result

Comment: It's preferable to `import` rather than use `os.system`. You are chaining `.get()`. The first one results in a string. The second one tries to operate on that string which causes the `AttributeError`. You don't show the body of `get_incident_id()` so I can't tell what it does with the argument or what type it should be. So you may want to concatenate the `get` results: `alert =  data.get('result') + data.get('alert') + data.get('value')` or create a tuple: `alert =  
 (data.get('result'), data.get('alert'), data.get('value'))`

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson I will try that yes I agree on the import I had tried that too lets see what I get

Comment: I gave that a try and got the same thing what I am hung up on is that both scripts work just not when one calls on the other so something in the handoff from script 1 and 2 must be happening ( I think)

Comment: For the `os.system()` case, if your `sys_id` or `args.host` might contain any `sh` special characters then they will need to be (and really should always be) quoted. As for the error. It's still as I described in my earlier comment. You don't show enough of your code to allow me to offer further suggestions. What modules are you importing? You're apparently using some global variables. How do they get their values? Etc.

Comment: I got it sorted out it was a race condition between the API results and the query